# How have a counter in Simulink such that increment with time step and be real positive number

Tags: matlab, counter, simulink

I have a vector of x(500*1) and I want to write a for loop in S-function (Simulink) such that for every time my model runs, I get `diff(x(i:i+1))` .
How can I have a counter variable( real positive number) that can be used?
I even tried to use some counter blocks but none of them works.
I need exactly like writing a for loop in mfile, but the counter needs to be incremented by t(Simulink time step)

Comment: What has a counter got to do with the requirement that you need `x(i+1)-x(i)`?

Comment: I do not get your question. But I need to have i which get incremented with t. how?